# Uploading video to users youtube account from symfony website

Tags: api, youtube

We want to integrate YouTube API into our website.

We have website which gets photos and videos from amazon s3 storage.

We would like to add feature which will allow user to upload video to his YouTube account from our website.

I spent whole day searching for it, but ended with nothing.

Any suggestion or help highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Vinay Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as someone who has not tried it before, I would start here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

"In addition, the API lets your application upload videos to YouTube or update existing videos."

Comment: Hi Patashu,

Thanks for your response. I had gone through this link earlier. The code which they have provided wont run on my localhost. The explanation is not clear. As they have not mentioned where all we need to make changes in order to run smoothly.